# Debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate strict.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, operating-system, apt

I have a problem my computer. I'm not really an expert. Few days ago I encountered a problem with my computer : it won't start, I discovered that my nvme0n1p5 partition was full (I'm not really sure if it's a partition or something else). To make my computer start again I deleted some file on this "partition" especially perl folder and docker folder. I choose those one because I installed them. It turns out that the perl I installed was a local perl and the perl I removed was necessary for the good work of the OS. So now when I try to install some package with apt I have this error :

debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (you may need to install the strict module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
) -- aborting
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.21) ...
Can't locate warnings.pm in @INC (you may need to install the warnings module) (@INC contains: /etc/
perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/
lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/sbin/addgroup line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/addgroup line 32.
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I don't know what to do and I would like to avoid re-installing linux on my computer.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

I tried many thing but nothing work, I tried to reinstall perl but I didn't succed (I think I only reinstall local perl and not the correct package for the OS). I hope I'm not talking nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Jeez, that's more an Ubuntu question.

(Supposing what you call "local Perl" is actually the system Perl.)

I *think* you need to re-install the system Perl (proper de-install first) but I don't know if that's even possible and if the system Perl was independently packaged.

Since apt is effected this might get hard. I think you should ask that in the Ubuntu community:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu

Sorry, I haven't administered Ubuntu for years. I hope they can help.

Comment: As previously mentioned, this really belongs on the Stack Exchange site for your distro. I wanted to add that could always reinstall `perl` from source